# Connection refused with Status-Code 0 in Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have built my Angular App and uploaded it to my Vserver. The app is connecting to my REST-API as follows:

```
public getContent(): Observable<void> {
 const headers: Headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 return this.http
 .get(this.api, JSON.stringify([]), { headers: headers })
 .map(response => response.json())
 })
 .catch((e) => this.errorHandler(e, this.router));
}
```

Furthermore the REST-API is based on express and is started on the same Vserver. It is listening to port 8080 on localhost.

When I try to start the Angular App I get the following error:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with statusCode = 0.

Comment: is your back-end server is running at `8080`?

Comment: In a angular http.get method you dont have to provide a request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your handle error function.

```
private errorHandler (error: Response) {  
   if (error.status === 0){
     this.router.navigate(['/page-you-want-to-navigate']);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is that I don't get an answer from the REST API from localhost.